# sort value graph matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm just started learning [python](/questions/tagged/python) and I got a little problem with my code
I need `yMin` start from `60` and `yMax=100`, but why my results like this?

[image]

Can someone please help me?

this my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


data = [
["{:.2}".format(0.80443), "{:.2}".format(0.84176), "{:.2}".format(0.84278), "{:.2}".format(0.82316),"{:.2}".format(0.82260)],
["{:.2}".format(0.71956), "{:.2}".format(0.77691), "{:.2}".format(0.77279), "{:.2}".format(0.74522),"{:.2}".format(0.74747)],
["{:.2}".format(0.84256), "{:.2}".format(0.83268), "{:.2}".format(0.84152), "{:.2}".format(0.84204),"{:.2}".format(0.83775)],
["{:.2}".format(0.71956), "{:.2}".format(0.77691), "{:.2}".format(0.77279), "{:.2}".format(0.74522),"{:.2}".format(0.74747)],
["{:.2}".format(0.80320), "{:.2}".format(0.83787), "{:.2}".format(0.83933), "{:.2}".format(0.82087),"{:.2}".format(0.82008)],
["{:.2}".format(0.71956), "{:.2}".format(0.77043), "{:.2}".format(0.76772), "{:.2}".format(0.74286),"{:.2}".format(0.74432)],
["{:.2}".format(0.83641), "{:.2}".format(0.83009), "{:.2}".format(0.83847), "{:.2}".format(0.83743),"{:.2}".format(0.83333)],
["{:.2}".format(0.71956), "{:.2}".format(0.77043), "{:.2}".format(0.76772), "{:.2}".format(0.74286),"{:.2}".format(0.74432)],
]


year = ['set1', 'set2', 'set3', 'set4', 'set5']
plt.plot(year, data[0])
plt.plot(year, data[1])
plt.plot(year, data[2])
plt.plot(year, data[3])
plt.plot(year, data[4])
plt.plot(year, data[5])
plt.plot(year, data[6])
plt.plot(year, data[7])
plt.xlabel('xx')
plt.ylabel('aa')
plt.title('bb')
plt.show()
```

If i change my format  ex : `"{:.2%}".format(0.80443)`

so this my results

[image]

I want to change the decimal number to percent and round it up to two decimal places. that's why I use `format` - @bigben

Comment: Why are you `.format`ting your data?

Comment: I want to change the decimal number to percent and round it up to two decimal places.@BigBen

Comment: But `.format()` returns a formatted *string*, which is not what you want.

Comment: @BigBen i give more pic for my problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're going about getting the percentages formatted incorrectly. Those values are strings after you format them, not numbers!

If you have a list like this, just multiply the float values by 100:

```
a = [0.80443, 0.84176, 0.84278, 0.82316, 0.82260]
data[0] = [ x * 100 for x in a ]
```

Then when you plot each list, you'll have values of `80.443, 84.176...`, etc.

If you want to control the range on the y-axis after multiplying and plotting, set:

`plt.ylim([60, 100])`

Which limits the y-axis to values between `60` and `100`.

EDIT:

To format the ticks on the y-axis, I recommend using the `ticker` methods in `matplotlib`:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 7))
plt.plot(year, data[0])
plt.ylim([60, 100])
ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(
    ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: "{:.2%}".format(x))
)
```